# Replacing a 4-gang standard switches with smart Kasa switches

Tags: electrical, grounding, neutral, smart-switch

I am trying to replace a 4-gang standard switches with Kasa smart switches.

1. How do I connect all the neutral white wires from the switches to the white neutral bundles in the box?
   There are too many wires to fit within one cap.
   Do I split into two or three caps and make sure all these white wires are internpconnected.
2. I see the bare copper wires for three of the switches are attached to the bottom metal parts of the switches. Do I just take these bare copper wires and connect to each of the green wires of my smart switches?
3. There is no bare copper wire attached to one of the switches which controls my LED strip under the kitchen cabinet. What do I do with the green wire from the smart switch? Do I just cap it off?
4. There is a 4th switch with black with black, black with red, black with pink and red with purple. How to connect the smart switch since there are no pink nor purple wires from the smart switch.

Thanks

[!(left side of 4-gang](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvvZY.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvvZY.jpg)

[image: right side of 4-gang]

[image: first two switches]

[image: 4th switch]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry I am not sure how to attach an image… I am new tot this. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I connect all the neutral white wires from the switches to the white neutral bundles in the box? There are too many wires to fit within one cap. Do I split into two or three caps and make sure all these white wires are internpconnected.

I like to use 8-port push-in wire connectors for these.  Ideal, gardner bender, and others make some.

> I see the bare copper wires for three of the switches are attached to the bottom metal parts of the switches. Do I just take these bare copper wires and connect to each of the green wires of my smart switches?

Yes

> There is no bare copper wire attached to one of the switches which controls my LED strip under the kitchen cabinet. What do I do with the green wire from the smart switch? Do I just cap it off?

No; all grounds should be connected together, and all switches should be grounded.

> There is a 4th switch with black with black, black with red, black with pink and red with purple. How to connect the smart switch since there are no pink nor purple wires from the smart switch.

We can't answer this without knowing where it goes, but it sounds like this is a 4-way switch, for a light fixture that has at least 3 switches controlling it.  You would need to replace it with a 4-way smart switch, and you'd need to do some investigating on the rest of the circuit to know which wires are which.  It could also be a 3-way circuit with power to the light first.

Comment: Hi, the old switch with no grounde wire attached has already tow ground wires attached to the metal box. Se photo. Do I just attached the smart switch ground to any one of the two screws.?   The fourth switch controls a pendant lightonly.. no other controls for this pendant

Comment: @raffi you can use the box screws to attach the smart switch ground, or if needed, you can add a pigtail off a ground screw and use a wire nut on multiple ground wires.  don't put multiple wires under one screw.

Comment: @raffi as for the pink and purple wires, that looks like a switch with built in transformer, or some type of low voltage control.  from your first description i thought you were talking about 14-2-2 wiring with a different color code.  you'd need to replace it with a smart switch of the same type (not sure if they exist off the top of my head).  is there a model number on that switch?

Comment: Hi, If youlook at my first image,(left side of 4-gang), both screws on the j-box have copper wires already, so I cannot add the ground from the switch to the box.  Not sure how to pigtail since the ground wires attached to the screws are very short.   So you are saying I can cap all four ground wires from the smart switches and then pigtail them to one of the copper wire from the screw? Can you send a drawing thank you so much

Comment: Yes it’s with a transformer I believe. I remember the electrician had to change the standard dimmer switch to this one because the standard dimmer didn’t work with the dimming. I will get model number. But now I would like to solve the issues of the other switches first..   there are total 6 neutral white plus 4 neutral from the new smart switch.. 8-port connector would not work would it? Should I use 2 5-port connectors and 1 4- port connector. As ther are total ten wires plus 2 pigtails.

Comment: i added a new image at the end for the neutral. Is this correct wiring?

Comment: … for the ground wiring, I added another image. Can you check if this is correct? There is no ground wire at the old switch 1.  So I bundle all the grounds a/f:   1.  Wires from box 2 and 3 + wires from smart switch A and B.  2. Wire from box 4 + wires from smart switch C and D. Appreciate your help. Raffi

Comment: @Raffi -- yeah, the far-right switch is actually a 0-10V interface dimming controller. The extra wires (pink/purple) send a separate control signal up to the light it's dimming.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, do you know how to replace this far-right switch with a smart switch? Or there’s nothing on The market right now?  Would you kindly look at my two drawings of neural and ground connections and see if they are good? Much appreciate your help.

Comment: @ickybus, hi can you help verify my last two drawings of the ground and neutral connections thanks

Comment: @Raffi -- 0-10V is rare in the smartswitch world